# When can a binary matrix be transformed into a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I have a $k \times n$ matrix $G$ over ${\mathbb F_2}$ that's full rank.
This can always be put in systematic form : $G \sim [I_k \mid P]$ where $I_k$ is a $k \times k$ identity matrix and $P$ is a $k \times (n-k)$ matrix. I'd like to impose this additional orthogonality condition on $P : P^t P = I_{n-k}$. I allow permutations of the columns of $G$ as additional operations. With these additional operations, when can I have $G \approx [I_k\mid P] : P^t P = I_{n-k}$?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "Put into" by what operations?

Comment: I'm allowing these two types of operations : the first is multiply by invertible matrix $U$ :  $ G \to U G = [I_k \mid P]$ and the second is a column permutations of $UG$ to make $P$ orthogonal (if possible).

Comment: If a column permutation of $P$ is orthogonal, so is $P$.

Comment: yes, but I'm allowing any combination of $(U,V)$ in any order; here $V$ is a permutation of order $n$. So it's equivalence under a larger group containing $GL_k({\mathbb F}_2)$  and $S_n$ as subgroups. (general linear group and symmetric group). Two matrices equivalent under these operations generate equivalent codes (hence the coding theory tag).